# Object is not iterable when replacing word called by function

Tags: python, python-3.x, basehttpserver

How do I get otherImages to return the string in it so that I can replace a word within it when called from 'narrow' method?

```
    def otherImages(self):
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<div id='menu_button'><a href='/narrow'><img src='../images/menu_button.png'></a></div>", "utf8"))
                                                               #^word I want to replace
    def contentList(self, skip_name=''):  # All content methods in list 
        methods = [self.title, self.containerDIV, self.heading, self.stopSection, self.offlineSection, self.onlineSection, self.endDIV, self.otherImages]
        for m in methods:
            if m.__name__ != skip_name:
                m()

    def narrow(self):
        try:
            self.reply()
            self.contentList('onlineSection')   # removed onlineSection
            for words in self.otherImages():
                words.replace("narrow", "index")
```

Comment: `otherImages` returns `None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the changes I made which solves my problem.  It allows me to edit the string when called from the 'narrow' method.

```
def otherImages(self):
    return["<div id='menu_button'><a href='/narrow'><img src='../images/menu_button.png'></a></div>"]


def narrow(self):
    try:
        self.reply()
        self.contentList('onlineSection')   # removed onlineSectionv
        for words in self.otherImages():
            words = words.replace("/narrow", "/")
            self.wfile.write(bytes(words, "utf8"))
        return
```

Comment: What changes were made? Why?

Comment: I should have clarified.  The question was that I wanted to know how to edit the string in method 'otherImages' when I call it from the 'narrow' method.  I posted the answer here.  The changes I made up top were adding some code such as the reply method and clarifying my question.  This post does answer my question.

Answer (score 3):

`self.otherImages` doesn't `return` anything!  When a function does not return an explicit value in python, it returns `None`.  You cannot iterate over `None`.

Comment: Why is not returning anything?

Comment: Because you don't have a `return` statement.  The only body of that method (at least, as far as you've shown us) is to write some data to a file.

Comment: You're still misunderstanding what's going on, unfortunately.  `self.wfile.write` is a _method_ that sends data to a _socket_ somewhere.  It's _return value_ is an integer, which can't be iterated over any more than `None` can be iterated over.  You're confusing return values with output in a way that's difficult to explain more clearly.  Writing to a file (or socket, or whatever) sends that data _somewhere else_.  When you _return_ something, you are making it available to the _calling method_.

Comment: I think I understand now.  So I could probably make 'otherImages' method return a string instead of writing.  Then manipulate that string in the 'narrow' method and take the output and write that.